# Http multipart/form-data not being

Tags: http, powershell, multipartform-data

What's wrong with the format of this http header that uses multipart/form-data? When you run the above code nothing gets posted, httpbin.org displays nothing in the forms section. I've checked it against other multipart/form-data packets and they're near similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some needed line breaks between the MIME parts, for starters:

```
$parameters = "
--$boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"name`"

upload.txt
--$boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"input.txt`"
Content-Type: text/plain

--$boundary--"
```

And you are not actually including any content for `input.txt` in the second MIME part at all.  Is that what you really want - to post a blank file?

> I've checked it against other multipart/form-data packets and they're near similar.

That implies that they are different, so you need to pay attention to those differences.

Comment: I've tried it that way, and with text one line underneath Content-Type: text/plain.

Comment: In a MIME part, you MUST include a blank line between the headers and the content.  You were not originally doing that. If you have done that now, and have also added text to send as the file content, and are still having problems, then please update your question with the new code you are using.  It would also be useful if you could also show the *raw data* that is actually being transmitted to the server. Use a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to capture that data. The request is probably still malformed in some manner you have not shown yet.

Comment: You were right, it was the white spaces I needed, also I had some white spaces in the front. Got rid of those and now it works.